# The relevance of MemoryStream class in System.IO namespace

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

It just occurred to why the MemoryStream class present in System.IO namespace?

Given that System.IO is all about Input/output operations wrt to Disks, etc AND the MemoryStream will be stored in memory.

Comment: Actually `System.IO` is about input/output operations on files and data *streams*.

Comment: Who says IO only has to do with disks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given that System.IO is all about Input/output operations wrt to Disks, etc

Nope, `System.IO` is all about input/output operations, and writing or reading from a memory stream is still IO in that sense.

Put it this way: if you save a file to a `MemoryStream`, is that not the *output* for the save operation? If you load an XML document from a `MemoryStream`, is that not the *input* for the parser?

The [namespace documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.aspx) states:

> The System.IO namespace contains types that allow reading and writing to files and data streams, and types that provide basic file and directory support.

Is `MemoryStream` not a "data stream" in your view? If not, why not?

Why namespace would *you* have put `MemoryStream` in?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to use a method that takes a `Stream` as input, but you don't have a file/network/ whatever stream to give it. In this case, you create a `MemoryStream` to provide an interface for writing data to what amounts to a byte array wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I second the venerable Jon Skeet's answer above, but I'll add a bit more reasoning.

Since the majority of operations coded to manipulate data streams operate on the System.IO.Stream abstract class (which can't be instantiated directly), all of these operations will be compatible with anything that inherits from System.IO.Stream, such as System.IO.FileStream or System.IO.BufferedStream. This is great for us devs - we can develop software working with data wherever we like, just as long as the storage media has a compatible System.IO.Stream-inherited class to handle the IO. You would agree, I hope, that filesystem access and so forth *should* live in System.IO.

However, even if you *do* think that memory isn't really IO (and I'd disagree there), the System.IO.MemoryStream class still inherits System.IO.Stream, and provides a nifty and consistent way to do the same stuff you'd do with files using System.IO.FileStream, just with transient in-memory storage instead.

As Jon says, since it inherits from System.IO.Stream, and provides an abstracted memory-backed store for input and output of data, where would you put it instead?